# How to set attribute to element from its content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to add to all elements with class `.double-text` attribute `data-content` with element's content value.

I tried something like that

```
$(function(){
  $('.text-double').attr("data-content", $(this).text());
});
```

But, obviously, it doesn't work.

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: While this has been closed as a dupe, I'm choosing to offer a solution as a comment: `$('.text-double').attr('data-content', function(){ return this.textContent; });` there's almost certainly no need to use `each()`, since the `attr()` method loops internally anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use `$.each` :

```
$('.text-double').each(function(){$(this).attr("data-content", $(this).text();});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `$.each()`

```js
$(function() {
  $('.text-double').each(function() {
    $(this).attr("data-content", $(this).text());
    console.log(this);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="text-double">Ele</p>
<p class="text-double">from</p>
<p class="text-double">SO</p>
```